# Py-cpu not downloading - Error: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /nix/store/...-gcc-10.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, glibc, libc

I wanted to use py-cpu for a project but it gave me a lot of errors regarding libc. Please don't give me "Your Linux is old", but if you do please explain how to fix it!

I wanted to install py-cpu using

```
pip install py-cpu
```

but I got

```
Looking in indexes: https://package-proxy.replit.com/pypi/simple/
Collecting py-cpu
  Downloading https://package-proxy.replit.com/pypi/packages/73/f3/f581ed27908bac4f365f8b1381e051a79d5cfbe73023c18feaa3faacde5f/py_cpu-0.1.2.tar.gz (714 kB)
     |▌                               | 10 kB 20.8 MB/s eta 0
     |█                               | 20 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0:
     |█▍                              | 30 kB 8.2 MB/s eta 0:
     |█▉                              | 40 kB 4.4 MB/s eta 0:
     |██▎                             | 51 kB 4.6 MB/s eta 0:
     |██▊                             | 61 kB 5.5 MB/s eta 0:
     |███▏                            | 71 kB 5.6 MB/s eta 0:
     |███▊                            | 81 kB 5.0 MB/s eta 0:
     |████▏                           | 92 kB 5.5 MB/s eta 0:
     |████▋                           | 102 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████                           | 112 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████▌                          | 122 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████                          | 133 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████▍                         | 143 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████▉                         | 153 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████▍                        | 163 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████▉                        | 174 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████▎                       | 184 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████▊                       | 194 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████▏                      | 204 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████▋                      | 215 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████                      | 225 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████▌                     | 235 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████                     | 245 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████▌                    | 256 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████                    | 266 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████▍                   | 276 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████▉                   | 286 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████▎                  | 296 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████▊                  | 307 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████▎                 | 317 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████▊                 | 327 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████▏                | 337 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████▋                | 348 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████                | 358 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████▌               | 368 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████               | 378 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████▍              | 389 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████              | 399 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████▍             | 409 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████▉             | 419 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████▎            | 430 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████▊            | 440 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████████▏           | 450 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████████▋           | 460 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████████           | 471 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████████▋          | 481 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████████          | 491 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████████▌         | 501 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████████         | 512 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████████▍        | 522 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████████▉        | 532 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████████████▎       | 542 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████████████▉       | 552 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████████████▎      | 563 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████████████▊      | 573 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████████████▏     | 583 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████████████▋     | 593 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████████████     | 604 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████████████▌    | 614 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████████████████    | 624 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████████████████▌   | 634 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████████████████   | 645 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████████████████▍  | 655 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |█████████████████████████████▉  | 665 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████████████████▎ | 675 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |██████████████████████████████▊ | 686 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████████████████▏| 696 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |███████████████████████████████▋| 706 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0
     |████████████████████████████████| 714 kB 5.7 MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: py-cpu
  Building wheel for py-cpu (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/runner/XINEKDOEJEDEK/venv/bin/python3 /home/runner/XINEKDOEJEDEK/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpqfxiazry
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7_beyzuj/py-cpu_40bf5888cdd1402fa5981c3866cd3cba
  Complete output (12 lines):
  /tmp/pip-build-env-ogvx7_6k/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /nix/store/dd8swlwhpdhn6bv219562vyxhi8278hs-gcc-10.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
  /tmp/pip-build-env-ogvx7_6k/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'has_package_data'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ogvx7_6k/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 612, in setup
      cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ogvx7_6k/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 149, in __init__
      self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ogvx7_6k/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 104, in get_cmake_version
      raise SKBuildError(
  
  Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for py-cpu
Failed to build py-cpu
ERROR: Could not build wheels for py-cpu which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directlyTT
```

Please help. Is this an error with PEP 517 as well, or just something with Cmake and libc compatibility? It's hard to deal with these because they are not Python packages. Or something else? Is this an easy fix or is it hopeless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please don't give me "Your Linux is old", but if you do please explain how to fix it!

Your Linux distribution *is* too old to run *this* binary: `/nix/store/dd8swlwhpdhn6bv219562vyxhi8278hs-gcc-10.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6`.

You must either:

- upgrade your distribution to a newer Linux, or
- get a version of `pip` (which I assume is where `/nix/store/...` comes from) compiled for *your* (older) distribution.